# Creating a setup.py based on my multiple python scripts

Tags: python, installation

I have these python scripts on the same folder/package(folder or package can be called the same? since everything in the same folder so I called it package? Am I right?):

My first python script lets called it "scriptA.py":

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
import scriptB
import scriptC
import enum
import sys
import os

"""
In this "scriptA", I will call both "scriptB" and "scriptC" to further do more processes.
"""
```

Then I have script "scriptB.py":

```
import pandas #since "scriptA" will already imported it should I not include it here? how can I do so? The rest will have the same issue too.
import glob
import os
```

Then I have script "scriptC.py":

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

My question:

How can I build a setup.py so that a user can just use pip install e. and it will install all the packages within all 3 scripts? Do you have an example or could you write be one to show me?

My personal message; Sorry somehow, my question has multiple questions inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the "Right" way to do this, but the following code will definitely work.

import pip #import the default package

```
def install(package):
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'): #later versions of pip do not have this attribute so just checking
        pip.main(['install', package]) #install the package name as passed in the parameter
    else: #if pip upto date then simply install the package
        pip._internal.main(['install', package]) #if 

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__': #you want to make sure that this doesn't run every time this file is imported somehwere and runs only when you run the particular script
    install('pandas') # you can use an entire list of all your required packages
```

Comment: Hi sir, could you include some explanation too if possible?

Comment: there you go !! Added comments

Comment: Can I ask what is the difference between your method and this which uses setuptool? https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: my code above installs packages into the current directory. whereas setup tools adds it to dist-packages inside your python folder (or virtualenv whichever path you have chosen)

Comment: I see but if possible, could you show me the example as in setuptools? Please so that I could learn.

Comment: Here, they have a very clean documentation. Its really easy to capture

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html